# What were the changes included in the Berlin/London fork?

Tags: hardforks

For Berlin there's EIP-2070 but it is an empty draft, and there's no spec for London.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can see what is included in every hardfork and their specifications: https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs

The EIP-2070 is hardfork meta, which (according to the https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2070) should not be implemented.